# PHP Javascript Mysql Insert

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I am trying to use java-script prompt to insert values into MySQL.  I have a html file and a php file.

The html files saved as `Test.html`:

```
 <button onclick="myFunction()">Create Project</button>

<script>
  function myFunction() {
      var project = prompt("Please enter project name");
      if (project != null && project !="") {
          $.post("conn.php", { project : project });
      }
  }
  </script>
```

The `conn.php`:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "Password";
$dbname = "db1";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$proj = $_POST['project'];
$sql = "INSERT INTO projects (project_name) VALUES ('$proj')";


if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

The conn.php works perfectly and inserts values if I remove the post parameter.

For example, instead of this:

```
$proj = $_POST['project'];
$sql = "INSERT INTO projects (project_name) VALUES ('$proj')";
```

if i use:

```
$proj = "NewProject";
$sql = "INSERT INTO projects (project_name) VALUES ('$proj')";
```

`NewProject` gets inserted into the database.

I am not sure if I am missing something in my index.html which is not posting the value in the prompt to php script.  I have tried `echo $_POST['project'];` instead of inserting into MySQL.  The echo is missing.

Comment: If `if(!isset($_POST['project']))`, you have a problem already. `$conn->query($sql) !== TRUE` .

Comment: You are not getting value in `$_POST['project']`.

Comment: @NitinKawane Yes

Comment: @PHPglue Do I have to wrap the insert statement inside the `if(!isset`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have run your given code, it runs only i have added the jquery link above script code

Please check this correction,

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Create Project</button>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  function myFunction() {
      var project = prompt("Please enter project name");
      if (project != null && project !="") {
          $.post("conn.php", { project : project },function(response){
             console.log(response);
         });
      }
  }
  </script>
```

and also i have added [isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) function with $_POST param in conn.php file

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "Password";
$dbname = "db1";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$proj = isset($_POST['project'])?$_POST['project']:'';
$sql = "INSERT INTO projects (project_name) VALUES ('$proj')";


if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Many thanks...It did work...I did had the script pointing to jquery.min.js...however, isset method did the magic i guess.  Thank you again.  I will accept your answer

Comment: The answer is very poor and no instruction to the OP was given regarding his mistake. Furthermore “isset” is not a “method” and the jquery should be added in the head section of the page. Overall very poor answer.